# Zebra stripe every two TRs in a row with CSS.

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to grey/stripe every two rows in a row. Its hard to explain. Here's a picture::
  |-^-^-^-^-^-|
  |-^-^-^-^-^-|
  |-------------|
  |-------------|
  |-^-^-^-^-^-|
  |-^-^-^-^-^-|
  |-------------|
  |-------------|
  |-^-^-^-^-^-|
  |-^-^-^-^-^-|
  |-------------|
  |-------------|

Comment: What is the grey/stripe? A background image?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/GQNUV/1/

```
table tr:nth-child(4n-1), table tr:nth-child(4n)  {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this to your preference, it should work

```
tr:nth-child(4n+1) { color: green; }
tr:nth-child(4n+2) { color: green; }
tr:nth-child(4n+3) { color: red; }
tr:nth-child(4n+4) { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a row for the headers, add thead and tbody and change css to:

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(4n-1), table tbody tr:nth-child(4n)  {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work properly, the `n` in `nth-child()` must be the same, but you change what you add onto the `n`. For this case, the numbers can only be one number apart. So you need `4n+1` and `4n`, or `4n+2` and `4n+3`, etc.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQNUV/2/)