# How can I create a 2 row zebra table in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, blazor-server-side

I've read [the bootstrap table documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/) and can't find anything there on this specific issue. Is there a way to create a 2 row zebra table, including 2 rows for the header? Like the following:

[image]

And if not, then I assume I have to just set the background & font color row by row. In that case, what should I set the class of each <th> and <tr> so they use the zebra colors based on the bootstrap theme and  class?

This is for a Blazor server side app although I think that's irrelevant to this question. For those that are curious, this is to fit the table on a webpage displayed on a cellphone.

Comment: You can do with css style by row

Comment: Is this a table or a grid?  I can see a way of making this work in a Grid more easily than a table.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis A plain old table

Comment: I've added an answer to demo how you can do it with a grid .  If you're not interested I'll delete it.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis It's a helpful answer to the question for others that find this. So please keep the answer there.

Comment: Duplicate of [Zebra stripe every two TRs in a row with CSS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004099/zebra-stripe-every-two-trs-in-a-row-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a creatively styled nth-child to solve for this.

```css
table {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

th {
  background-color: #c7c2c2;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
}

table tr:nth-child(4n-1),
table tr:nth-child(4n) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
    <th>Col 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
    <th>Col 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
    <td>thing</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/s4vyn2jx/3/

Comment: Wow - I was not aware of tr:nth-child(). Follow on question - how can I set it to the bootstrap theme appropriate colors? thanks

Comment: Glad to help. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by Bootstrap theme "appropriate" colors? If you just need the colors from the classes, you can retrieve them from the classes and replace the color values I used. Is that what you're refrerring to?

Comment: I was hoping there was a property like BootstrapAlternateTablrRowBackgroundColor and if I assign that, then the table colors match the theme I select.

Comment: Bootstrap does offer table striping, but as far as I can tell they alternate by every other row, rather than two at a time. These are Bootstrap's table striping colors... .table-primary = #cfe2ff, #c5d7f2 .table-secondary = #e2e3e5, #d7d8da .table-success = #d1e7dd, #c7dbd2 .table-info = #cff4fc, #c5e8ef .table-warning = #fff3cd, #f2e7c3 .table-danger = #f8d7da, #eccccf .table-light = #f8f9fa, #ecedee .table-dark = #212529, #2c3034. Will any of these colors work for your project?

Comment: Thank you - I didn't realize those were hardcoded. I assumed they would be changed based on the bootstrap theme.

Comment: I think I understand what you meant by Bootstrap theme colors - perhaps you have the option to change themes and the table colors would automatically update based on the new color theme...is that correct? Since this was a custom coded table, it falls outside of Bootstraps dynamic predefined classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a grid:

````cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div class="row bg-primary text-white fw-bold">
    <div class="col-4">
        Category
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        Date
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        Location
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        Description
    </div>
</div>
@foreach (var companyEvent in _companyEvents)
{
    <div class="@this.GetRowCss(companyEvent.Uid)" @onclick="() => this.OnSelectValue(companyEvent.Uid)" >
        <div class="col-4">
            @companyEvent.Category
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            @companyEvent.Date
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            @companyEvent.Location
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            @companyEvent.Description
        </div>
    </div>

        }
@code {
    private Guid _selectedValue;

    private void OnSelectValue(Guid value)
    => _selectedValue = value;

    private string GetRowCss(Guid value)
        => _selectedValue == value ? "row bg-light" : "row";

    private List<CompanyEvent> _companyEvents = new()
    {
    new CompanyEvent(Guid.NewGuid(), "Party", "Event Center", DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now), "Host The Party,...."),    
    new CompanyEvent(Guid.NewGuid(),"Sign Up", "Office", DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now), "Staff the Desk,...."),
    new CompanyEvent(Guid.NewGuid(),"Blood Drive", "Hospital", DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now), "Give Blood,...."),
    };

    public record CompanyEvent(Guid Uid, string Category, string Location, DateOnly Date, string Description);
}
 Grid then:

```csharp
````